# Who regulates the information related to the nutrients of a product?

Tags: health, regulations, food

On almost all the products we buy in supermarkets, we see a table like the following:

[image]

However, can I producer give wrong information in these kinds of explanatory notes on the products? Who regulates these? Who checks whether the supplied information is correct?

Edit: In Germany, U.K. and Turkey.

Comment: In what country?

Comment: @RonBeyer see the edit

Answer (score 1):

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia) [new-zealand](/questions/tagged/new-zealand)

The standards are set by [Food Standards Australia New Zealand](https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/labelling/Pages/default.aspx) and policed by New Zealand and the Australian states and territories.